# getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame() gives different values in Android 2.2, 2.3 (but not 2.3.3)

Tags: android, android-activity

I've got an `Activity` which uses

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
```

to determine the useable screen space and decide where to place images.

Returning to the Activity after I click the hardware "back" button to leave the `Activity`, the rectangle values are

```
(0,0,800,480)
```

However, returning to the Activity after I click the hardware "home" button to leave the `Activity`, the rectangle values are

```
(0,38,800,480)
```

which throws off the display and the image placement.

How can I ensure I get a consistent values when calling

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
```

no matter how I left the app?

UPDATE: Thanks to @Reno for helping test; it seems to be dependent on Android version than the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welp, if you read the comments in the source, it admits that this method is kind of broken

```
    public void getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(Rect outRect) {
    if (mAttachInfo != null) {
        try {
            mAttachInfo.mSession.getDisplayFrame(mAttachInfo.mWindow, outRect);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            return;
        }
        // XXX This is really broken, and probably all needs to be done
        // in the window manager, and we need to know more about whether
        // we want the area behind or in front of the IME.
        final Rect insets = mAttachInfo.mVisibleInsets;
        outRect.left += insets.left;
        outRect.top += insets.top;
        outRect.right -= insets.right;
        outRect.bottom -= insets.bottom;
        return;
    }
```

You will have to ignore the outRect.top value for versions < 2.3.3

Comment: Why ignore outRect.top for versions < 2.3.3?  I'm seeing non-zero values when running on versions > 2.3.3 (xoom, nexus 7...), which takes the top status bar into account.  I don't have a device that's running < 2.3.3 but when I run the emulator I see the same thing.  I'm just looking to get the current height and width of the usable area and getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame() seems consistent, but it sounds like you've seen something different.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[here](http://mrtn.me/blog/2012/03/17/get-the-height-of-the-status-bar-in-android/) is a link to get status bar directly instead of calculate it. It will avoid any issue of getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame which is really inconsistent through platforms and devices.

---

It's on wayback machine here: https://web.archive.org/web/20130421032443/https://mrtn.me/blog/2012/03/17/get-the-height-of-the-status-bar-in-android/

And here is the content:

> Get the Height of the Status Bar in Android MAR 17TH, 2012

> Sometimes
> in Android, the flexible layout system is not flexible enough and you
> need to make some computations inside your code. In these
> computations, you may need to subtract the size of the status bar.
> Stackoverflow gives you some answers, but they all rely on the fact
> that te status bar is shown at the time you make your computation. If
> you are in full screen mode, by having called for instance:

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)`
It doesn’t work.

> The height of the status bar is contained in a dimension resource
> called status_bar_height. It’s not part of the public resources, so
> you can’t access it directly from your code with
> android.R.dimen.status_bar_height. You can however compute it at
> runtime with the following code:

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() {   
  int result = 0;
  int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");   
  if (resourceId > 0) {
    result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);   
  }   
  return result; 
}
```

> You need to put this method in a ContextWrapper
> class.
>
> Hope it helps.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: and thats why people should post some content :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are times when you need to know the precise dimensions of the available space for a layout when in an activity's onCreate.
After some thought I worked out this way of doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16691531/2202013
It does not use getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame and is hopefully future proof.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did this:

```
    Rect rectangle = new Rect();
    getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9  /* android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD */ ) {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659652/getwindowvisibledisplayframe-gives-different-values-in-android-2-2-2-3-but-no/7660204#7660204
        rectangle.top = 0;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not exactly following the issue, but I'd like to use getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame() to get the area available for my application minus all status bars.   Right now I'm calling getWindow()getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame() for all versions of android and it works fine, with a non-zero 'top' value when there's a status bar at the top.  Will this code be reliable on all versions of android?  Note: I'm calling that when the user hits a button.

Comment: You mentioned "UPDATE: Thanks to @Reno for helping test; it seems to be dependent on Android version than the device.", could you help me out and let me know what the differences were in versions?  I'm just nervous that one version will return the screen size without status bars and one will return the rect with status bars.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry; I cannot.  I haven't worked on Android in over a year; this post was from 18 months ago.  I simply don't remember.  :-(  You're probably better off asking a new question.  :-)