# Using window in not Activity class?

Tags: android, android-activity, window, statusbar, titlebar

Before,I saw this snippet to find `Height of statusbar?(and also Tiltebar)` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3356263/1043882):

```
Rect rectgle= new Rect();
Window window= getWindow();
window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
int StatusBarHeight= rectgle.top;
int contentViewTop= 
    window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
int TitleBarHeight= contentViewTop - StatusBarHeight;
```

Yesterday,I tried to use this snippet in an `AsyncTask` class.So I send instance of my Activity to `AsyncTask` class,in `onCreate` of Activity:

```
LongOperation loper = new LongOperation(this, vg, vArray, hintsArray,x_positionArray, y_positionArray);//Here `this` refers to current Activity
loper.execute("YES");
```

In doInBackground of AsynkTask class I only did:

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

And in `onPostExecute` method I copy above code to calculate height of statusbar and titlebar.But App crashes,without any useful log in logcat.Then I comment some lines like this:

```
Rect rectgle = new Rect();
    Window window = activity.getWindow();
//  window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
//  int StatusBarHeight= rectgle.top;
    contentViewTop = window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT)
            .getTop();
//  int TitleBarHeight= contentViewTop - StatusBarHeight;
```

and App works fine.So it seems that

> window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);

causes App crashing,But I do not know why?Did I do some thing incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are running your app in Android 2.3.3 then there might happens that app got crash.Because this method is kind of broken.So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659652/getwindowvisibledisplayframe-gives-different-values-in-android-2-2-2-3-but-n) solution might help you.

Hope this helps :)